# How to specify to swagger-php that my parameter is going to be a file?

Tags: php, symfony, swagger

I use the newest swagger-php https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php with attribute style (not annotation). I want to specify that my field is going to be a `file`. But I have no idea how to do that. I have the following code in my controller:

```php
class FileController extends AbstractController
{
    #[OA\Parameter(parameter: 'file', name: 'file')]
    #[Route('/api/upload-file', name: 'app_upload_file', methods: ['post'])]
    public function uploadFile(ImageDto $imageDto, ConstraintViolationListInterface $errors): Response
    {
        return $this->json(
            [
                'success' => $errors === null,
                'errors' => $errors,
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

and the `ImageDto` is:

```php
class ImageDto implements RequestObjectInterface
{
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    public UploadedFile $file;

    public function getFile(): UploadedFile
    {
        return $this->file;
    }
}
```

All I need is to specify that here
[image]
I want a file field, not the text one.

To use DTO I use `nelexa/request-dto-bundle` package. But it does not matter in this context. The matter is, I have no idea how to specify that my parameter is going to be a file. And the source code is not so readable, at least for me. I will give you an example of
the `#[Property(...)]` constructor source code. Take a look at this:

```php
 /**
     * @param array<string,Examples>    $examples
     * @param array<string,string>|null $x
     * @param Attachable[]|null         $attachables
     */
    public function __construct(
        ?string $parameter = null,
        ?string $name = null,
        ?string $description = null,
        ?string $in = null,
        ?bool $required = null,
        string|object|null $ref = null,
        ?Schema $schema = null,
        ?array $examples = null,
        ?string $style = null,
        ?bool $explode = null,
        // annotation
        ?array $x = null,
        ?array $attachables = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct([
                'parameter' => $parameter ?? Generator::UNDEFINED,
                'name' => $name ?? Generator::UNDEFINED,
                'description' => $description ?? Generator::UNDEFINED,
                'in' => Generator::isDefault($this->in) ? $in : $this->in,
                'required' => !Generator::isDefault($this->required) ? $this->required : ($required ?? Generator::UNDEFINED),
                'ref' => $ref ?? Generator::UNDEFINED,
                'style' => $style ?? Generator::UNDEFINED,
                'explode' => $explode ?? Generator::UNDEFINED,
                'x' => $x ?? Generator::UNDEFINED,
                'value' => $this->combine($schema, $examples, $attachables),
            ]);
    }
```

I have no idea what the leverage should I use to specify that I want this field to be a file.

Comment: I might be completely off, but take a look here https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php/issues/876

Comment: @GuidoFaecke after walking around that links, I have found the solution! Thanks for the feedback. I'm gonna publish the solution here.

Answer (score 3):

It works for me

```
OA\RequestBody(
        content: [new OA\MediaType(mediaType: "multipart/form-data",
            schema: new OA\Schema(
                properties: [
                    new OA\Property(property: "upload", type: "file", format: "binary"),
                    new OA\Property(property: "num_chunks", type: "integer")
                ]
            )
        )],
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

After several minutes of walking between old code examples on the internet, I have ended up with something like that:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Dto\Files\ImageDto;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolationListInterface;
use OpenApi\Attributes as OA;

class FileController extends AbstractController
{
    #[OA\RequestBody(content: [new OA\MediaType(mediaType: 'multipart/form-data')])]
    #[OA\Parameter(parameter: 'file', name: 'file', schema: new OA\Schema(type: 'file') )]
    #[Route('/api/upload-file', name: 'app_upload_file', methods: ['post'])]
    public function uploadFile(ImageDto $imageDto, ConstraintViolationListInterface $errors): Response
    {
        return $this->json(
            [
                'success' => $errors === null,
                'errors' => $errors,
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

So, all I needed was just to add the `schema: new OA\Schema(type: 'file')` to my `#[OA\Parameter]` attribute.

`#[OA\RequestBody(content: [new OA\MediaType(mediaType: 'multipart/form-data')])]` I'm not sure that this has any effect, but it adds this:

[image]

And ok, let it be.

I also have published the whole class of the controller. I hope you note this line:

```
use OpenApi\Attributes as OA;
```

I have it done because all the examples go with this `OA` and no one of the tels what is the `OA` and where is the `OA` source. I was a bit confused at the beggining. Now I know that OA is `use OpenApi\Attributes as OA`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also reference your DTO directly in the controller and map the properties then:

```php
final class FileController extends AbstractController
{
    #[OA\RequestBody(
        content: new OA\MediaType(
            mediaType: "multipart/form-data",
            schema: new OA\Schema(
                ref: new Model(type: ImageDto::class)
            )
        )
    )]
    #[Route('/api/upload-file', name: 'app_upload_file', methods: ['post'])]
    public function uploadFile(ImageDto $imageDto, ConstraintViolationListInterface $errors): Response
    {
        return $this->json(
            [
                'success' => $errors === null,
                'errors' => $errors,
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

```php
final readonly class ImageDto implements RequestObjectInterface
{
    #[OA\Property(type: "string", format: "binary", example: "my_image.png")]
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    public UploadedFile $file;
}
```